# The higher the page, the slower the response (pagination with EF)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagination, linq-to-entities

I'm doing pagination with ASP.NET MVC / EF / Linq-To-Entities (code below).

I have a performance problem: **the higher the page is, the slower the response**  (from the server to the client). I'm not sure if this problem is in the "database side" or the "application side".

The slowest case is fetching the last page (page 1038), in which the following code takes like 40 seconds aprox.:

```
IQueryable<Measurement> measurements = dbContext.Measurements
  .Where(...)
  .Where(...)
  .OrderByDescending(m => m.Date);

int count = 0;

await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    count = measurements.Count();
});

IEnumerable<dynamic> pageOfItems = new List<dynamic>();

await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    pageOfItems = measurements
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .Select(m => new { .... })
            .AsEnumerable();

    Console.WriteLine("sql query = " + pageOfItems.toString());
});

return new JsonNetResult()
{
    Data = new
    {
        count = count,
        measurements = pageOfItems,
        page = page,
        pageSize = pageSize,
    }
};
```

I took the generated query (*as you can see there's a* `Console.WriteLine` *printing the query*) an I tested it directly in the database. This way I confirmed that the query is slow but: **not that slow**. It takes like 4 seconds aprox.

After all these information, one would be tempted to say that the problem is in the "application side":

4 seconds in database **v/s** 40 - 4 = 38 seconds in the application

...but if I fetch a low page (eg: page 1), the response from the server to the client is very quick (less than a second). So, I'd like to discard a problem in serializing the JSON data sent to the client, ie: `return new JsonNetResult() { ... }`

Questions are:

1. Is it efficient to do pagination with Skip and Take? The generated SQL query is something like:

   SELECT TOP (pageSize)
        ...
      WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 103700
2. How can I measure the time the database is taking to execute the query when the application is sending the query to the database? I measured the time of the database executing the query "sent by me". I want to do the same but when the query is sent by the application.

Other relevant information:

- The `count = measurements.Count()` is very fast.
- There is an index in the `Date` column

Comment: Measure the database speed (assuming you are using SQL Server) using the SQL Profiler. Also, as for the index on that table, `Date` is likely not so useful, it's what's in the `Where` clause that would benefit from an index.

Comment: The where is pretty simple: `where MeasurerId = 5`, and `MeasurerId` is also indexed. Sometimes I also have `where Date.Year == ...`. Isn't the `Date` index helpful for the `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: There are 2 queries here. Have you looked at the one generated by `count = measurements.Count()` ? Does that query include the order by?

Answer (score 0):

F*cking Windows Azure was the problem.
I spent ALL THE DAY (1pm - 2am) figuring what the problem was.

I've always used "web" database tier, which is going to be retired... so I gave a try to "basic", and then to "standard S0".

Those two are sh**t.

Went back to "web tier" and everything runs super fast...
Page 1038 takes only two seconds (it is in fact slower than fetching page 1 but its hardly noticeable)

The problem: *"Web and Business edition databases will not be available after September 2015"*...